# How to change this function to recursive

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function `find_numbers()` which returns all n-digit numbers whose sum of digits is divisible by 2.

For example, find_numbers(2) will return:
`[11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99]`

Question: How can I change find_numbers() to be recursive? (in python)

```
def find_numbers(n: int):
   result = []

   for i in range(10**(n - 1), 10**n):
      if (sum_of_digits(i) % 2 == 0):
         result.append(i)

   return result

# helper function to sum all digits of a number
def sum_of_digits(n: int) -> int:
   result = 0
   for digit in str(n):
      result += int(digit)
   return result
```

I've just created this recursive version, but it doesn't work. I don't know what is wrong in the following code:

```
def find_numbers(n: int):
   def find_numbers_helper(n: int, i: int):
      if (i < 10 ** n):
         if (sum_of_digits(i) % 2 == 0):
            return [i].append(find_numbers_helper(n, i + 1))            

   return find_numbers_helper(n, i=10 **(n-1))
```

Comment: Another question is *why*..

Comment: For information, your second function is `sum(map(int, str(n)))`.

Comment: The sum of a number's digits = the first digit + the sum of the rest of the digits.

Comment: and this is a one liner: find_numbers = lambda n:[i for i in range(10**(n - 1), 10**n) if sum(map(int, list(str(i)))) % 2 == 0]

Comment: ok yes maybe it can be solved in one line but I really want to see a solution as a recursive version of find_numbers. I have more complex task to do and I just simplified it to simplier problem only to ask for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursivity often requires approaching the problem differently.  Most notably as a refinement of a simpler solution.  For example, by adding digits to numbers of the larger N-size making the total even only on the last digit.  You can keep track of the even/odd state of the sum of digits as you add them at each recursion level.

Here is an example as a recursive generator:

```
def evenDigits(N,prefix=0,odd=0):
    if N == 1: # only add odd or even digits at last position
        yield from (prefix*10+d for d in range(odd,10,2))
        return
    for d in range(prefix==0,10): # start at 1 when prefix is zero
        yield from evenDigits(N-1,prefix*10+d,(odd+d)%2)
```

output:

```
for n in evenDigits(3): print(n)
101
103
105
107
109
110
112
114
116
118
121
123
...
987
989
990
992
994
996
998
```

This is much different from an iterative approach where you would typically just filter numbers on the sum of their digits:

```
def evenDigits(N):
    yield from (n for n in range(10**(N-1),10**N) if sum(map(int,str(n)))%2==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution!

```
def find_numbers(n: int) -> list:
   def find_numbers_helper(result: list, n: int, i: int):
      if (i < 10 ** n):
         if (sum_of_digits(i) % 2 == 0):
            result.append(i)
         
         find_numbers_helper(result, n, i + 1)

   result = list()
   find_numbers_helper(result, n, i=10 **(n-1))

   return result
```

Can it be improved (not by removing recursion)?

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem in your solution

- The first time you call `find_numbers_helper()`, the value of `i` will be `10^x`, so `sum_of_digits(i)` will be `1` and `sum_of_digits(i)% 2 == 0` is always `False`. Hence the statement `return [i].append(find_numbers_helper(n, i + 1))` is unreachable. As a result, `find_numbers_helper()` is called only once and returns nothing.
- The second problem is that your solution is essentially an iterative approach (loop through all the numbers less than `10^n` and check the sum of their digits). To write a recursively function, you need to have a recursive approach that I will give the example below.

#### My solution

- The idea of this solution is to choose each digit from left to right, each time we choose 1 digit and recursively call to choose the next digit. At each step we store current number `num` and `remainder` of "sum of the digits" divided by 2. Recursion ends when we choose the last digit (choose even digit if the `remainder` is even and odd digit in the opposite case).
- Below is an example code:

  ```py
  def find_numbers(n: int, num = 0, remainder = 0):
      if n == 1:
          return [num * 10 + digit for digit in range (remainder, 10, 2)]
      result = []
      for digit in range (num == 0, 10):
          result += find_numbers(n - 1, num * 10 + digit, (remainder + digit) % 2)
      return result
  ```

  ```py
  print(find_numbers(1))
  # [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
  print(find_numbers(2))
  # [11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99]
  ```